# How to draw line Transit mode in Android Google map?

Tags: android

Currently working in Google Map App.I want to use Google transit API in android application for draw line Transit. But code just to draw line driving. Can you have me fix code to draw line Transit!

Here my code:

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {
    final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
    private GoogleMap myMap;
    private   double src_lat ;
    private   double src_long ;
    private  double dest_lat ;
    private  double dest_long ;


    MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        String gps1,gps2;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        gps1 = bundle.getString("origin");
        gps2 = bundle.getString("destination");

        String[] myLocation = new String[2];
        myLocation = gps1.split(",");
        src_lat = Double.parseDouble(myLocation[0]);
        src_long = Double.parseDouble(myLocation[1]);
        String[] myLocation1 = new String[2];
        myLocation1 = gps2.split(",");
        dest_lat = Double.parseDouble(myLocation1[0]);
        dest_long = Double.parseDouble(myLocation1[1]);
        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
        LatLng srcLatLng = new LatLng(src_lat, src_long);
        LatLng destLatLng = new LatLng(dest_lat, dest_long);

        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(srcLatLng).title("Source place"));

        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(srcLatLng));

        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(destLatLng).title("Destination place"));

        // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        myMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(srcLatLng,12));
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();


        // Polyline line = myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(srcLatLng, destLatLng).width(5).color(Color.RED));

        connectAsyncTask _connectAsyncTask = new connectAsyncTask();
        _connectAsyncTask.execute();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_legalnotices:
                String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(
                        getApplicationContext());
                AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this);
                LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
                LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
                LicenseDialog.show();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

        if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
        }

    }

    private class connectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main2Activity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching route, Please wait...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            fetchData();
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if(doc!=null){
                NodeList _nodelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("status");
                Node node1 = _nodelist.item(0);
                String _status1 = node1.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                if(_status1.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
                    NodeList _nodelist_path = doc.getElementsByTagName("overview_polyline");
                    Node node_path = _nodelist_path.item(0);
                    Element _status_path = (Element)node_path;
                    NodeList _nodelist_destination_path = _status_path.getElementsByTagName("points");
                    Node _nodelist_dest = _nodelist_destination_path.item(0);
                    String _path = _nodelist_dest.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue();
                    List<LatLng> directionPoint = decodePoly(_path);

                    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(Color.RED);
                    for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
                        rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                    }
                    // Adding route on the map
                    myMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
                    markerOptions.position(new LatLng(dest_lat, dest_long));
                    markerOptions.draggable(true);
                    myMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                }else{
                    showAlert("Unable to find the route");
                }


            }else{
                showAlert("Unable to find the route");
            }

            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }

    Document doc = null;
    private void fetchData()
    {
        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=");
        urlString.append(src_lat);
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(src_long);
        urlString.append("&destination=");//to
        urlString.append(dest_lat);
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append(dest_long);
//          urlString.append("&mode=transit&sensor=false&region=fr");
        urlString.append("&sensor=true&mode=driving");
        Log.d("url", "::" + urlString.toString());
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;
        URL url = null;
        try
        {
            url = new URL(urlString.toString());
            urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = (Document) db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());//Util.XMLfromString(response);
        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ParserConfigurationException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void showAlert(String message){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this);
        alert.setTitle("Error");
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.setMessage(message);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }

    private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;
    }
}
```